# Surveymonkey API - Delete response after download

Tags: api, surveymonkey

Is it possible to delete individual responses? If so how? I've looked over the API methods on https://developer.surveymonkey.com/ but I'm either blind/stupid or it doesn't exist. Thanks

Comment: You didn't miss anything on the methods page - the API is read only currently, there is no way to modify or delete responses.

Comment: Thanks Miles. Perhaps in the meanwhile I can use Selenium to log in and purge responses.